# Getting a users complete achievement list through Google+ API

Tags: google-plus

I run a cross-platform achievement tracker, where the user can gather and show their achievements from xbox, psn, steam etc.

Now I want to add support for achievements attached to a users google account (google+ achievements). Can I do that through the API somehow? Been searching but can't find anything.

Comment: Google+ doesn't have achievements. Are you talking about [Google Play Games Services](https://developers.google.com/games/services/web/gettingstarted)

Comment: I probably do... I find it a bit unclear as to which services starts and ends where... I thought the Google Play Games Services was for a particular game; i.e. if you develop a game and have achievements; and that the users complete list of games/achievements would be on their + page... But is there a list accessible from the Google Play Games Services? Can't find any there either.

Comment: Google+ doesn't include or display any game achievements. Actually I don't think there is anyway to get achievements for other apps.